# Computer Generated Olympic Theme Song

Tags: popularity-contest, music

Try to regenerate the olympic theme song, "Bugler's Dream" using the programming language of your choice. The language/platform used must be able to emit the physical sound. Only playing the main melody (trumpets) is required, but doing more would be great.

You must generate all the tones yourself - you cannot play back a midi/wav or any other sound file.

Here are the sound files for reference:

http://www.jonfullmer.com/music-of-the-month/buglers_dream/buglers_dream.mp4
http://www.armory.com/~keeper/1/bugdream.mid

Good luck!

Comment: Try? C: "" 0 characters, I win.  Do, or do not, but don't bother otherwise.

Comment: @NickT you better use perl/python/bash/something else. "" does not compile in C.

Comment: Twinkle Twinkle Little Star was a simple song, and the question gave the exact notes you had to produce, making it objective. This does not, and any attempt to simplify the (rather complex) music is going to sound horrible. To make it objective, I think either the exact notes should be defined in the question, or it should be changed to popularity contest. But if it is a popularity contest, I guess answerers will have to post a link to their output (as far as I know you can only attach picture files here, correct me If I`m wrong.) So complex, it could be more about data compression than music!

Comment: I would be fine changing this to a popularity contest, I just thought with the olympics, it would be cool if there was a code-golf that played the olympic song. Maybe even cooler if the code was arranged creatively, such as to create the olympic rings in ASCII or something like that. Can popularity contest still be graded on how short the source code is?

Comment: @mniip it does compile (with warnings); an empty file won the IOCCC one year for shortest quine.

Comment: @NickT ``In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'``

Comment: @mniip http://www.ioccc.org/years-spoiler.html#1994_smr

Comment: @NickT Now if you actually take a look at the [Makefile rule](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/Makefile) for smr, it does not use the C compiler

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 2576

**Code**

```
Sound[{{d, {0., 1.2}}, {a, {0., 1.2}}, {e, {0., 1.2}}, {f, {1.2, 2.2}}, {e, {1.2, 2.2}}, {e, {2.2, 2.4}}, {f, {2.2, 2.4}}, {a, {2.4, 3.}}, {c, {2.4, 3.}}, {b, {3., 3.6}}, {e, {3., 3.6}}, {d, {3.6, 4.2}}, {a, {3.6, 4.2}}, {e, {3.6, 4.2}}, {a, {4.2, 4.8}}, {c, {4.2, 4.8}}, {b, {4.8, 5.4}}, {e, {4.8, 5.4}}, {b, {5.4, 5.8}}, {e, {5.4, 5.8}}, {b, {5.8, 6.}}, {e, {5.8, 6.}}, {b, {6., 6.6}}, {e, {6., 6.6}}, {d, {6.6, 6.9}}, {a, {6.6, 6.9}}, {b, {6.9, 7.2}}, {e, {6.9, 7.2}}, {c, {7.2, 7.5}}, {a, {7.2, 7.5}}, {a, {7.5, 7.6}}, {c, {7.5, 7.6}}, {b, {7.6, 7.8}}, {e, {7.6, 7.8}}, {d, {7.8, 8.1}}, {a, {7.8, 8.1}}, {a, {8.1, 8.4}}, {c, {8.1, 8.4}}, {b, {8.4, 9.6}}, {e, {8.4, 9.6}}, {d, {9.6, 10.8}}, {a, {9.6, 10.8}}, {e, {9.6, 10.8}}, {f, {10.8, 11.8}}, {e, {10.8, 11.8}}, {e, {11.8, 12.}}, {f, {11.8, 12.}}, {a, {12., 12.6}}, {c, {12., 12.6}}, {b, {12.6, 13.2}}, {e, {12.6, 13.2}}, {d, {13.2, 13.8}}, {a, {13.2, 13.8}}, {e, {13.2, 13.8}}, {a, {13.8, 14.4}}, {c, {13.8, 14.4}}, {b, {14.4, 15.}}, {e, {14.4, 15.}}, {b, {15., 15.4}}, {e, {15., 15.4}}, {b, {15.4, 15.6}}, {e, {15.4, 15.6}}, {b, {15.6, 16.2}}, {e, {15.6, 16.2}}, {d, {16.2, 16.5}}, {a, {16.2, 16.5}}, {b, {16.5, 16.8}}, {e, {16.5, 16.8}}, {c, {16.8, 17.1}}, {a, {16.8, 17.1}}, {a, {17.1, 17.2}}, {c, {17.1, 17.2}}, {b, {17.2, 17.4}}, {e, {17.2, 17.4}}, {d, {17.4, 17.7}}, {a, {17.4, 17.7}}, {a, {17.7, 18.}}, {c, {17.7, 18.}}, {e, {18., 19.2}}, {a, {18., 19.2}}, {c, {18., 19.2}}, {d, {19.2, 20.4}}, {a, {19.2, 20.4}}, {e, {19.2, 20.4}}, {f, {20.4, 21.4}}, {e, {20.4, 21.4}}, {e, {21.4, 21.6}}, {f, {21.4, 21.6}}, {a, {21.6, 22.2}}, {c, {21.6, 22.2}}, {b, {22.2, 22.8}}, {e, {22.2, 22.8}}, {d, {22.8, 23.4}}, {a, {22.8, 23.4}}, {e, {22.8, 23.4}}, {a, {23.4, 24.}}, {c, {23.4, 24.}}, {b, {24., 24.6}}, {e, {24., 24.6}}, {b, {24.6, 25.1}}, {e, {24.6, 25.1}}, {b, {25.1, 25.2}}, {e, {25.1, 25.2}}, {b, {25.2, 25.8}}, {e, {25.2, 25.8}}, {d, {25.8, 26.1}}, {a, {25.8, 26.1}}, {b, {26.1, 26.4}}, {e, {26.1, 26.4}}, {c, {26.4, 26.7}}, {a, {26.4, 26.7}}, {a, {26.7, 26.9}}, {c, {26.7, 26.9}}, {b, {26.9, 27.}}, {e, {26.9, 27.}}, {d, {27., 27.3}}, {a, {27., 27.3}}, {a, {27.3, 27.6}}, {c, {27.3, 27.6}}, {b, {27.6, 28.8}}, {e, {27.6, 28.8}}, {d, {28.8, 30.}}, {a, {28.8, 30.}}, {e, {28.8, 30.}}, {f, {30., 31.}}, {e, {30., 31.}}, {e, {31., 31.2}}, {f, {31., 31.2}}, {a, {31.2, 31.8}}, {c, {31.2, 31.8}}, {b, {31.8, 32.4}}, {e, {31.8, 32.4}}, {d, {32.4, 33.}}, {a, {32.4, 33.}}, {e, {32.4, 33.}}, {a, {33., 33.6}}, {c, {33., 33.6}}, {b, {33.6, 34.2}}, {e, {33.6, 34.2}}, {b, {34.2, 34.7}}, {e, {34.2, 34.7}}, {b, {34.7, 34.8}}, {e, {34.7, 34.8}}, {b, {34.8, 35.4}}, {e, {34.8, 35.4}}, {d, {35.4, 35.7}}, {a, {35.4, 35.7}}, {b, {35.7, 36.}}, {e, {35.7, 36.}}, {c, {36., 36.3}}, {a, {36., 36.3}}, {a, {36.3, 36.4}}, {c, {36.3, 36.4}},{b, {36.4, 36.6}}, {e, {36.4, 36.6}}, {d, {36.6, 36.9}}, {a, {36.6, 36.9}}, {a, {36.9, 37.2}}, {c, {36.9, 37.2}}, {e, {37.2, 38.4}}, {a, {37.2, 38.4}}, {c, {37.2, 38.4}}} 
/. {n_, t_} :> SoundNote[n, Round[t, .1], "Trumpet", SoundVolume -> 0.7]] 
/. {a -> "C#5", b -> "D#5", c -> "F4", d -> "F5", e -> "G#4", f -> "G#5"}
```

---

### Output

Bugler's Dream, Trumpet track.

[image: buglers dream]

---

### Saving to file

```
Export["bugler.mid", bugler]
```

> bugler.mid